# Is it possible to create .mobi files with python? if so, how?

Tags: python, kindle

I want to be able to create .mobi files with python, but i haven't found anything about it after an hour of searching. I don't want to use Calibre or softwares like it, just plain python.

Comment: calibre is an open source software that is written in python ... download their source and look at it to see what its doing.... and look at the file definition for mobi files http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend to take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/mhl/guardian-for-kindle), if you don't want to use `calibre` (which is great and has a CLI). While [this script](https://github.com/mhl/guardian-for-kindle/blob/master/make-guardian-ebook.py) has created for creating a `.mobi` for the Guardian, you can modify it to your taste.

Comment: As far as I understand the script (see last lines), the mobi conversion is handled by `kindlegen`.